# Pinterest style stacking by using CSS3 only

Tags: css

Is it possible to do a pinterest style layout/stacking of items on a page with css only?

I imagine CSS3 might have something that could do this kind of layout with columns perhaps.

I've already read a tutorial, but it requires using javascript and absolute positioning to do the stacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3 columns. It will stack the items vertically. http://jsfiddle.net/qLVXQ/

```
div.pinterest {
    width: 400px;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 0;
}
div.pinterest > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: perfect, thanks. IE9 doesn't support columns from what I've read, but IE10 will. what a surprise :P

Comment: If you want a cross browser solution there is this polyfill: http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/ . I haven't tried it on the above example though.